# Exporting Release with Flash Builder 4.5 (Flex)

Tags: flexbuilder, flash-builder

when trying to export the release build of an application I get the following error:

"One or more warnings were found while building the release version. You may choose to ignore these warnings"

So, following the advice from another post, in the "Additional Compiler Arguments" part of the project properties, I included a "-warnings=false" statement. I also unchecked "Enable Warnings"

This not only doesn't this remove the warnings, but it also doesn't prevent the error upon release.

The actual warnings are related to:
"widgets.Search:SearchWidget is a module or application that is directly referenced. This will cause widgets.Search:SearchWidget and all of its dependencies to be linked in with widgets.TOC:TOCWidget. Using an interface is the recommended practice to avoid this."

The original application code comes from outside my organization and completely re-writing it is not an option. There are no references in the code I can see that would directly relate each of these to each other, and I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

After some time-consuming troubleshooting I was able to isolate where the warnings came from. Unsurprisingly, it was from an "import" statement that was left over from something I experimented with months ago, but never actually used. It doesn't cause a problem during debugging so I forgot all about it. The problem was fixed as soon as I commented out the offending line.